# How to get chrome extensions to perform function in background on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension to sign into a wifi system, and currently have it set so that they must click on the extension to sign in. But instead I want it to just sign them in every 30 minutes, using background js I want it to check a cookie I saved if 30 minutes has passed and then sign in. But instead it only works when you first install it.

Here is my manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "BCA Auto Login",
  "description": "This extension automatically signs you into the BCA wifi",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [ "cookies", "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["http://*/*","https://*/*"],
    "js": ["jquery.js","login.js"]
  }],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["jquery.js", "background.js"]
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }

}
```

Here is my background.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    chrome.cookies.get({ url: 'urlofCookie.com', name: 'time' },
    //the cookie is a time in minutes
    function (cookie) {
        if (cookie) {
            var current = new Date();
            if((current.getMinutes() - cookie) >= 30){
                $.ajax({
                    type : 'POST',
                    url : 'https://signinURL',
                    data : {
                        username: 'username',
                        password: 'password',
                    },
                    success : workedFunction
                });
            }
        }
        else{
            cookieNotFound();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only call the function on page load, so no wonder it does not execute after that. If you want to perform an action periodically, you can use the **[chrome.alarms API](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/alarms.html)** and **[create an alarm](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/alarms.html#method-create)** to fire every 30 minutes (you don't even need the cookie unless you use it for other things as well).

E.g.:

```
var wifiAlarmName = "wifiSignIn";

chrome.alarms.create(wifiAlarmName, {
    delayInMinutes: 0,
    periodInMinutes: 30
});

chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(function(alarm) {
    if (alarm.name === wifiAlarmName) {
        // Sign in
        ...
    }
});
```